# Mettete i fiori nei vostri cannoni

Tags: word-meaning, single-words

Buongiorno,

Sto cercando il significato dell'espressione (Pugliese?) “metti i fiori nei tuoi cannoni”. Non riesco a trovarla su Internet.

Grazie.

Comment: Ciao, la frase corretta dovrebbe essere "mettere i fiori nei cannoni". La frase non credo sia pugliese ma si usa in tutta Italia. È un messaggio di pace, un po' come il più famoso "fate l'amore non fate la guerra"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La tua frase non è corretta: invece di “metti i fiori nei tuoi canoni” devi scrivere:

```
Mettete i fiori nei vostri cannoni
```

**Il significato**

È un messaggio pacifista: normalmente nei cannoni si inseriscono proiettili o bombe per uccidere e distruggere: il mettere dei fiori, che sono innocui, rende il cannone non più un oggetto di morte ma di vita.

**L'origine**

La band italiana dei Giganti scrisse negli anni '70 questa canzone, “Proposta (Mettete dei fiori nei vostri cannoni)”; [**qui**](http://testicanzoni.mtv.it/testi-I-Giganti_60427/testo-Proposta-(Mettete-dei-fiori-nei-vostri-cannoni)-3171744) puoi trovare il testo completo, mentre [**qui**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxklQ3YHpvs) puoi trovare la canzone.

È un modo alternativo, e diventato esso stesso di uso comune, del più celebre “Fate l'amore non fate la guerra”.

Comment: Joe, grazie per le tue risposte e interventi, ma potresti fare un po' più caso all'ortografia, alla punteggiatura etc.? C'è gente che viene qui per imparare o migliorare il proprio italiano... Grazie.

Comment: @DaG: Ciao, hai ragione, cercherò di essere più preciso. Grazie per le correzioni

Comment: @DaG: Una curiosità, il gruppo musicale si chiama "I Giganti" non "Giganti", nel caso specifico è corretto mettere dei invece di de I?

Comment: Non c'è un vero bisogno di usare “de”. Anche se molti la usano, è meglio dire, semmai, «la band di “I Giganti”» o meglio ancora «la band “I Giganti”». Questo, se è importante mettere in evidenza l'articolo; altrimenti lo si ingloba nella preposizione articolata, che è stata inventata apposta, come in «l'autore dei “Promessi sposi”».

Comment: OK, grazie per la risposta ;)

Comment: @dag, se uno scrive "l'autore de "I promessi sposi", "de" può chiamarsi preposizione **disarticolata**?

Comment: @DaG «La band di "I Giganti"» suona proprio male, secondo me!

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Infatti, nel caso sarebbe de "I Giganti" non di

Comment: @JoeTaras Ma DaG dice che è meglio usare "di", in questo caso non mi sembra...

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Ok, giusto.

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Come già dicevo, visto che “di i” suona strano, hanno inventato le preposizioni articolate. E comunque, in questo caso è proprio “la band di/de/dei [nome]” che è insolito: è meglio “la band [nome]” oppure il nome e basta se si assume che il lettore capisca che è un gruppo musicale.

Comment: @DaG Va bene che, dopo "band", è meglio togliere la "di" e si taglia la testa al toro, ma《l'autore dei "Promessi Sposi"》non mi piace neanche, mi sembra di cambiare il titolo all'opera...

Comment: Capisco, @CarLaTeX. Trovi approfonditi i pro e i contro delle varie possibilità in [una nuova domanda e risposta](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/8051/dei-promessi-sposi-di-i-promessi-sposi-o-de-i-promessi-sposi) che ho inserito stimolato da questo scambio.