# “dei ‘Promessi Sposi’”, “di ‘I Promessi Sposi’” o “de ‘I Promessi Sposi’”?

Tags: prepositions

Visto che nei commenti a un'[altra domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/8039/mettere-i-fiori-nei-tuoi-cannoni) era emerso questo dubbio, ne faccio una domanda a sé.

Quando si menziona un titolo che comprende un articolo (per esempio *I Promessi Sposi*) preceduto da una preposizione, e in particolare da “di”, che fare:

1. lasciare “di” seguita dal titolo immutato: “l'autore di ‘I Promessi Sposi’”;
2. modificare “di” in “de”: “l'autore de ‘I Promessi Sposi’”;
3. ricorrere a una preposizione articolata: “l'autore dei ‘Promessi Sposi’”?

Comment: Ottima domanda!

Comment: In un esercizio che abbiamo fatto a lezione (guardare un video di YouTube per poi rispondere ad alcune domande) c'era scritto "ecco chi è la scrittrice **de** *L'amica geniale*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Serianni, nel suo *Italiano* (ed. Garzanti) risponde in modo molto chiaro esattamente a questo dubbio (in una scheda a p. 578):

> Di fronte a un titolo o a un nome di città o di ditta cominciante con un articolo (*I Promessi Sposi*, *La Spezia*, Ristorante *Il Caminetto* ecc.) ci si può trovare in dubbio ogni volta che la sequenza sia preceduta da una preposizione. Nella lingua parlata (e anche in quella scritta, almeno in tutti i casi in cui non sorgano equivoci) la soluzione più semplice è anche la più raccomandabile: la preposizione si fonde con l'articolo iniziale («La stesura *dei* “Promessi Sposi”», «Sono partita *dalla* Spezia questa mattina», «Abbiamo cenato *al* “Caminetto”»).
>
> Nei casi in cui sia necessario rispettare l'integrità della denominazione si hanno varie alternative, nessuna priva di inconvenienti:
>
> §1. Adoperare la preposizione semplice, così come si farebbe davanti a un cognome (*di Lo Surdo*): *di “I Promessi Sposi”*, *a “Il Caminetto”* (inconveniente: creare delle sequenze che non esistono, né sono mai esistite, nella lingua parlata);
>
> §2. Scindere la preposizione articolata nelle sue componenti: *de “I Promessi Sposi”*, *da La Spezia*, appoggiandosi all'esistenza nell'italiano antico e poetico di forme scisse delle preposizioni articolate (inconveniente: non si riesce ad evitare del tutto la controindicazione del punto 1 [*a “Il Caminetto”*]) e comunque si dà vita a forme puramente artificiali, estranee all'italiano di oggi);
>
> §3. Ricorrere a un aggettivo o a un'apposizione che separi preposizione e denominazione: *del romanzo “I Promessi Sposi”*, *al ristorante “Il Caminetto”* (inconveniente: in diversi casi la soluzione ha il sapore dell'espediente e comunque non riesce a risolvere tutti i casi: con *La Spezia*, ad esempio, non potrei dire * *dalla città La Spezia* perché sarei obbligato a usare la preposizione *di* ricadendo in pieno nel nostro piccolo problema).

Anche a p. 133, parlando in generale degli articoli, si parla del problema, sottolineando l'artificialità delle forme con “de” e “ne” (anche perché etimologicamente la “e” deriva da quello che poi è diventato l'articolo) e concludendo che

> L'uso consigliato (e seguìto) da questa *Grammatica* è quello di fondere sempre preposizione e articolo iniziale (almeno per i titoli), così come si fa parlando: «il protagonista del *Santo* di Fogazzaro», «un articolo sulla *Gazzetta di Parma*», «il Moravia degli *Indifferenti*».

Quindi il succo è che sia meglio usare sempre le preposizioni articolate, tranne i rari casi in cui sia indispensabile citare l'articolo a sé (poniamo, in un confronto fra *I Promessi Sposi* e un altro libro intitolato *Promessi Sposi*), nel quale si ricorrerà a malincuore a una delle tre soluzioni di cui sopra.