# Si dice “in settore alimentare”?

Tags: prepositions, articles, phrase-choice

Ieri ero con mio amico e gli ho chiesto che lavoro fa. Ha risposto “fornaio”.

Allora ho detto "Lavori in settore alimentare?" e lui ha riso. Secondo lui si dice "lavori nel settore alimentare" oppure "lavori in campo alimentare".

Perché non si dice "in settore alimentare"?

Comment: Benvenuto/a! Mi sono preso la libertà di rendere la domanda in italiano più scorrevole. In particolare “a detto” dovrebbe essere “ha detto” e “fa” è senza apostrofo (che si usa se è in modo imperativo).

Comment: Quanto alla domanda, la mia sensazione è che “settore alimentare” sia concreto, mentre “campo alimentare” sia astratto. Comunque si può dire anche “nel campo alimentare”.

Comment: Sono questioni idiomatiche: “in settore alimentare” suona strano, come detto da uno straniero che non padroneggia gli articoli, ma non c'è una vera regola generale che proibisca o consenta l'uso degli articoli, a parte alcuni casi particolari.

Comment: @dag non capisco questioni idiomatiche

Comment: @micina96: In ogni lingua ci sono frasi che in teoria sono corrette dal punto di vista della grammatica, ma che però “suonano strane” e a un nativo non verrebbe in mente di dire. Per esempio, “vado a mangiare nella casa di Mario” sarebbe corretto grammaticalmente, ma nessun italiano lo direbbe: non è _idiomatico_. Si dice invece “vado a mangiare da Mario”.

Comment: @dag grazie, grazie, sei bravo. E sei in più carino! :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Provo a dare una mia spiegazione semplice, per quanto possibile.

La regola dell'articolo determinativo dice che esso si usa per indicare qualcosa che è unico, invece che generico. Per esempio:

- dammi una mano  (una delle due che hai)
- dammi la mano destra (l'unica mano destra che hai)

Però:

- dammi una mano destra

normalmente non si dice perchè la "mano destra" è una sola, e non si può "rendere generica". Quando l'articolo è assente, è un po' come se ci fosse quello indeterminativo.

Vediamo *settore*. Un "settore" è una parte precisa di qualcos'altro, a sua volta preciso (settore di un edificio, di un negozio, settore di una attività). Perciò, come per "mano destra", "settore alimentare" indica una cosa unica. In questo caso
"settore alimentare" è una parte dell'ambito lavorativo, è una cosa unica, quindi vuole l'articolo determinativo.

Vediamo *campo*. Un "campo" (agricoltura) solitamente non è recintato, non è "una parte" di qualche cosa di preciso. Il termine, piuttosto che indicare "una parte di qualcosa", indica un insieme omogeneo di cose, come "un campo di patate", oppure un ambiente generico che si distingue in modi sottili da altri ambienti.
L'uso del termine in senso astratto è ampio e libero: "in campo aperto", "scendere in campo", "il nemico in campo", "le forze in campo", "il gioco sul campo"; sempre ambiti.

Perciò si dice "in campo medico" per dire "in ambito medico", "campo industriale" per indicare l'ambiente dell'industria, eccetera; si usa per denotare contesti in modo sfumato. Per questo motivo la scelta dell'articolo o della sua assenza è più libera, perchè "campo" non denota *con forza* una cosa singola in contrapposizione  all'insieme che lo contiene. Certo, il "campo filosofico" è una parte di tutto ciò che la mente può immaginare o ragionare, ma i suoi confini sono poco delimitati, si può sovrapporre ad altri ambiti, possono esserci svariati "campi filosofici". Ecco perché non suonano male "in campo medico" e "nel campo medico": la prima frase è solo un poco più incerta.

Comment: say reinstate monica studio la spiegazione, bel esempio di mano destra/sinistra, grazie per provare semplice. Poi forse faccio domande.

Comment: Ho provato a essere semplice ma non sono riuscito. La domanda è molto difficile. Fa' pure domande quando vuoi.

Answer (score 4):

Si tratta di un tipico errore che fanno gli stranieri la cui lingua d'origine non utilizzi gli articoli determinativi (o definiti), come per nelle lingue slave. In italiano, invece, è spesso  necessario usare questo tipo di articoli.
A complicare le cose c'è, innanzi tutto, il fatto che bisogna capire se usare l'articolo definito ("il settore") o indefinito ("un settore"). Capire quando usare i secondi è in genere facile, non fosse altro perché già si utilizzano nella lingua di provenienza. Occorre molta più pratica per capire quando usare l'articolo determinativo.
La [regola generale](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/articolo_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/) è che va usato in riferimento:

1. a una categoria generale di persone, animali, oggetti, concetti;
2. a qualcuno o qualcosa di già noto a chi legge, parla o ascolta.

Nel suo caso si parla appunto di una categoria generale, quindi "il settore alimentare". Ci sono casi più complessi. Ad esempio (visti i tempi di lockdown), è corretto dire "lavoro in casa" o  "lavoro da casa", invece si dice "lavoro da un hotel".

Un altro caso ostico è "in campo" o  "in ambito". Qui usare l'articolo determinativo rende la comunicazione più naturale; mentre ometterlo richiama uno registro linguistico burocratico.

La seconda complicazione sta in ciò che mentre si può dire "in un settore", non si può dire "in il settore", sarebbe cacofonico. Si dirà, quindi, "nel settore".

Comment: Mi sembra una buona risposta, @antonio. Unicamente, riguardo all'ultimo paragrafo, è veramente un problema di cacofonia? O è semplicemente che le [preposizioni articolate](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/9405/) funzionano sempre così e basta?

Comment: Infatti, la cacofonia c'entra ben poco: “\*inil\*” è una successione di suoni normalissima in italiano.

Comment: @Charo Propongo prima un inusuale quesito: le tartarughe delle Galapagos hanno lo scudo (il guscio) a sella perché sono nate così o perché è più comodo nutrirsi dei frutti in alto? Per Darwin la risposta è semplice: quelle che possono allungare di più il collo hanno soppiantato le altre nel processo evolutivo, avendo più chance di vita. Qualcosa di simile accade all'evoluzione della lingua, in cui alcune forme parlate, più "efficienti", ne rimpiazzano altre e vengono poi recepite sotto forma di regole morfosintattiche.
(segue)

Comment: @Charo  ... Orbene, nel link a corredo della mia risposta si trova anche la regola in questione: detta della fusione tra articolo e preposizione. Si tratta di un regola che esiste anche in altre lingue latine. Ad esempio, per lo spagnolo, "a + él"  diventa "al". "En el" si mantiene separato, tuttavia appare pronunciato come se fosse un'unica parola. In italiano dire certe locuzioni quali:  "con" spazio "il"; "fra" spazio "il"; "in" spazio "il" è faticoso. Lo stress del parlante va rapportato alla frequenza delle preposizioni. (segue)

Comment: @Charo ... Quindi, per locuzioni meno frequenti la fusione non avviene ("fra il") o è facoltativa ("con il"). Per modificatori sintagmatici che possono capitare anche più volte in una frase, dove la pronuncia della stessa, con le corrette pause, diventerebbe una sorta di scioglilingua, le fusioni sono obbligatorie.

Comment: Grazie, @antonio. In spagnolo, "él" è il pronome personale che corrisponderebbe all'italiano "lui", non va confuso con l'articolo "el" ("él" ed "el" sono infatti omofoni): "a" + "él" si scrive (e si pronuncia) "a él", invece "a" + "el" diventa "al". Non direi, però, che sia un problema di cacofonia: se fosse così, anche "a él" sarebbe cacofonico.

Comment: @Charo: Scusami, un errore di digitazione, intendevo  "a + el", ossia [uno dei due casi](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposici%C3%B3n#Contracci%C3%B3n_con_el_art%C3%ADculo) di fusione in spagnolo (l'altro è "del"). Peraltro la stessa regola sui nomi propri, "Varios periodistas de El País", si applica anche da noi in "Diversi giornalisti de La Stampa" (da notare il "de").

Comment: @Charo: Per quanto riguarda cosa sia la cacofonia non esistono evidentemente regole esplicite, ci sono solo sensibilità individuali e lungi dal voler imporre ad altri la mia. A te potrebbe suonare naturale pronunciare ripetutamente una sequenza quale "in il", magari proprio perché, se spagnola, abituata a dire "en el", a me risulterebbe pesante scandire tante volte "in-pausa-il". Ovviamente lo stesso non si applica a parole tipo "vinile", perché non c'è separazione.

Comment: @antonio: Riguardo al tuo commento precedente, dà un'occhiata a [questa risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/8051/).

Comment: @antonio: “femmINILe”, “vINILe”, “i bambINI Lo sanno”, “homo homINI Lupus” etc. Esattamente qual è il problema nel pronunciare la sequenza “i-n-i-l”?

Comment: Va bene, @antonio: io esprimerei l'ultimo paragrafo in un modo leggermente diverso, ma si tratta di un piccolo dettaglio che forse non è tanto importante in relazione alla domanda fatta. Per il resto, mi sembra una buona risposta.

Comment: @dag riguardo a "in il" e "vinile", io pronuncio la N differentemente nei due casi (può essere che io sia l'unico italiano a farlo?). La N di "in il" la genero con la parte posteriore della lingua, come quando dico "incavo", mentre in "vinile" la genero con la punta. E' un tentativo di esprimere la pausa tra IN e IL.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Non mi è chiaro questo fatto della pausa. È verissimo che in italiano al fonema /n/ corrispondono diversi foni, ma la differenza principale è se dopo la “n” c'è una vocale, o una consonante e di che tipo. Se devo dire “esco con il cane”, a me non viene da interporre alcuna pausa tra “con” e “il”; lo pronuncio come se fosse scritto “conilcane”. A te sì? E non vedo perché “in il” dovrebbe essere diverso, qualora si dicesse.

Comment: @DaG magari sbaglio, ma a me viene così: "con il cane" lo dico con *con* un po' più accentata e la *n* "dietro"; "conilcane" lo dico con la *n* "davanti" e più sonora. Non c'è effettivamente pausa, ho usato quella parola perché l'ha usata antonio per dire che le parole sono due invece di una - o almeno credo -; quello che intendo io è la separazione tra due parole.