# Come interpretare «il dispetto mi spingeva»?

Tags: meaning, phrases

C'è un passaggio nel [*Fu Mattia Pascal*](https://it.wikisource.org/wiki/Il_fu_Mattia_Pascal/12):

> Perdetti, da quella sera in poi, il dominio di me stesso; cominciai a sforzare apertamente la timidezza di Adriana; chiusi gli occhi e m’abbandonai, senza più riflettere, al mio sentimento. 
>
> Povera cara mammina! Ella si mostrò dapprincipio come tenuta tra due, tra la paura e la speranza. Non sapeva affidarsi a questa, indovinando che il dispetto mi spingeva, ma sentivo d’altra parte che la paura in lei era pur cagionata dalla speranza fino a quel momento segreta e quasi incosciente di non perdermi; e perciò, dando io ora a questa sua speranza alimento co’ miei nuovi modi risoluti, non sapeva neanche cedere del tutto alla paura.

Nelle parole «il dispetto mi spingeva» si dice del dispetto di chi verso chi? Leggo che è il dispetto di Papiano verso Mattia Pascal, cioè la noncuranza di Papiano verso i sentimenti più naturali di Mattia Pascal come il suo volere esser lasciato in pace; ma credo possa anche essere quello di Mattia Pascal verso Papiano, cioè la sua irritazione e stizza verso Papiano. Allora, quel dispetto lo spingeva a far che cosa? Leggo che lo spingeva ad andar via dalla casa di Paleari, ma credo possa anche essere qualcosa che non riesco ad immaginare. Non sono sicuro di avere raccolto tutte le chiavi di significato in questo brano.

Vorrei assicurarmi se la mia interpretazione sia corretta o no, e se no, vorrei capire qual è corretta. Grazie!

Comment: A single closing vote does not represent the opinion of the whole community. I reopened the question, which I find quite interesting.

Comment: Ho fatto una modifica nel post seguendo la raccomandazione fatta in [questa risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/8052/).

Comment: I am sorry for rash speaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ho letto il romanzo e adesso ho riletto alcuni passaggi per poter ricordare i dettagli.

Ho sempre interpretato questa espressione come il dispetto (nel senso di sentimento di stizza, di contrarietà, di irritazione) che sente Mattia Pascal nelle veste di Adriano Meis per la situazione in cui Terenzio Papiano fa il tiranno e Adriana (la "povera cara mammina" del brano) si sottomette quasi come una schiava, che è spiegato in questa frase del testo:

> Provai, dopo quelle confidenze, una stizza violenta nel vederla così sottomessa e quasi schiava dell'odiosa tirannia di quel cagliostro.

Confidenze che, tra l'altro, fanno sapere a Mattia Pascal che Terenzio Papiano pretende sposare Adriana.

Questa frase è soltanto un esempio, ma, come ha menzionato l'OP nei suoi commenti, nel romanzo sono descritte parecchie circostanze di una situazione che provocava una grande stizza in Mattia Pascal, irritazione che sicuramente è percepita da Adriana.

Adriana ha l'impressione che questo sentimento possa spingere Adriano Meis (cioè, Mattia Pascal) ad agire nel modo descritto nel passo, ossia, che possa indurlo "a sforzare apertamente la timidezza" di lei e a mostrare questi "nuovi modi risoluti". Ha percepito un cambiamento nell'atteggiamento di Adriano verso di lei, ma  se n'accorge che è accaduto poco dopo l'arrivo in casa di Terenzio Papiano, che fino a quel momento era in viaggio a Napoli.

Comment: Grazie; ma in questo caso sarebbe piuttosto la stizza per le maniere vessanti di Papiano ("l’irritazione ch’egli mi cagionava con quel suo tratto da vessatore servizievole": duole parlare con qualcuno che pretende d'essere un amico e fa troppe richieste "benevoli"): infatti Adriana non poteva sapere delle confidenze di Caporale, almeno sul momento (la stessa sera)... Un'interpretazione plausibile, almeno logica. Questo brano non è del tutto semplice, forse è stato complicato con lo scopo di rendere così la "perplessità" di Adriana che la faceva comportarsi "impacciata".

Comment: In effetti, quella stessa sera non poteva sapere delle confidenze della Caporale, ma qui l'autore non descrive quello che accade quella sera, ma "da quella sera in poi": Adriana finisce sicuramente per accorgersi che la situazione gli causa stizza, irritazione. E, come hai detto, è anche l'irritazione per le maniere di Papiano (e il modo servile di agire di Adriana): si tratta dell'irritazione di Adriano Meis (Mattia Pascal) per tutta la situazione.

Comment: Credo che l'autore descrivi quella sera anch'essa. Le maniere di Adriana nel dialogo sopra, a proposito del fratello di Papiano, sono ben descrivibili dalle parole "paura e speranza". Mi pare una buona regola di narratura, di dare sempre esempi alle descrizioni generali, e Pirandello sembra fare sempre così nel romanzo. Ma è immateriale, perché l'argomento vale lo stesso. C'è da essere irritato, e si può vederlo e indovinarne le cause più o meno.